# Simulation js websockets in PHP

Tags: websocket, phpwebsocket

Here is js code

```
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };

websocket.send('some_message');
```

It connects to wsUri, bind some handlers and send "some_message" to the server. How can I do that in PHP? I want to send message to wsUri from another php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a WebSocket Client-Server library for PHP and simply use the Client part in your script. There seems to be a number of available solutions:

- [phpws](http://code.google.com/p/phpws/)
- [ratchet](http://socketo.me/)
- [php-websocket](https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket) by [lemmingzshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949444/lemmingzshadow)